# Lightbox with ability to open dialog at same time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a photo gallery that I am working on and trying to do something that I can't figure out how to, or whether it is possible.

The page is at:
http://www.randykrohn.com/gallery/pictures.php?EventID=263

When you click a thumbnail it opens the large file in a Fancybox.  In the bottom of the lightbox (the title, description area) there are icons to comment, share, or save the file options.  I want to open a dialog box that someone can comment on the photo without having to close the lightbox if possible.  Have tried several options to no avail.

I would be glad to take any suggestions on possible workarounds to get it to perform as desired without going to a java applet and or opening new windows.

Thanks!

Comment: This is just about adding the desired fields to the bottom of your "lightbox". To do so would probably be rather simple too, but in order to help you the code and library you use is necessary. Do you use the standard lightbox? Or the lighbox2? Or some other library that does the same thing. Remember, all those libraries simply creates and shows a DIV. And all you want to do is change the content of that DIV.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a larger z-index value for the comment dialog.

Comment: I did try that, and to no avail

Answer (score 0):

You either need to include the Jquery and the Lightbox code in the new modal window so you can call a new lightbox from there, or send a command back to the parent page to do so.

I think you also need to ensure that the first lightbox is launched as an Iframe so it can act independently of the page.

Comment: Is there any down side to opening it in an iframe?

Comment: I will lose the ability to run it as a gallery at that point....?  Not sure, I guess if that is the worst thing that happens, it guess that would be ok.

Comment: The lightbox should have configuration options of how to open it i.e Iframe, Inline, just a photo. The Iframe option allows the modal window to operate independent of the page that launched it.